# 2 groups - some participants are only in one group, some in both: how to analyze?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, model-selection, survey

I want to compare questionnaire scores about symptom X arising from trigger Y vs. trigger Z. Usually I'd go for a between-subject design. However, some participants (~50% of the sample) have had X as a result of both Y and Z, so I asked them to complete the questionnaire twice, once thinking about the time that X got triggered by Y, and once thinking about the time that X got triggered by Z. The easiest way to analyze this would be with a paired-samples t-test for these participants and with an independent t-test for the rest. However, I'd lose power because I'd be breaking my sample into two. Is there a way I can compare Y vs. Z taking into account the whole sample?
These are two ideas I have, and would love to receive thoughts on them:

- Mixed model (fixed: score ~ trigger; random: trigger|participant) → I tried it and it seemed to work but I'm not sure the results make sense, specially because some participants only have 1 datapoint (only 1 trigger), so what would their slope mean?
- GLM in which I do not only take into account trigger but also add a column in the design matrix to account for participants which have both triggers. For example, in the following design matrix, participants 1 and 3 had both triggers, so they get a "1" in column "both". This would be like a between-subjects design but accounting for the fact that some participants had both triggers (it's not particularly interesting if this has an effect but I do hypothesize a small effect: higher questionnaire scores in people with both triggers).

[image: design matrix for GLM]

Any thoughts about the best way to go in this case would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: "Mixed model (fixed: score ~ trigger; random: trigger|participant) → I'm afraid it wouldn't work because some participants only have 1 datapoint (only 1 trigger)" Did you actually try this? My first impulse would be to do that and see what happens. (It may or may not work but if you get a result it should be OK.)

Comment: It should be possible to fit that model at least in a Bayesian manner, although this would require prior distributions and an MCMC sampler.

Comment: I'm not that keen on the GLM approach because this ignores the dependence between observations from the same participant.

Comment: @ChristianHennig, yes, I tried this and it seemed to work but I'm not sure the results make sense, since what does a slope mean for participants with just 1 trigger? (I edited the question with this information). Regarding Bayesian, I'm afraid it'd be a bit too complicated and I don't have enough experience with that. And I agree that with that GLM approach the dependencies between observations would be ignored... Would it be somehow possible to take the column "participant" in the design matrix (making it categorical somehow) to account for this?

Comment: If I understand the situation this sounds like a form of overlapping samples testing. There's a few posts and comments onsite that discuss overlapping samples tests. (To find relevant comments you will need to use an external search if the site, the internal search engine works for posts not comments)

Comment: @erpo Thinking it through, I'd probably use random: 1|participant (assuming the R-way of specifying these), i.e. random intercept. This basically means that the same participant is to be expected to have more similar results from the two triggers than different participants (of course one can wonder whether this makes sense in your specific situation using subject-matter knowledge). A random slope is indeed harder to get the head around.

Comment: "Would it be somehow possible to take the column "participant" in the design matrix (making it categorical somehow) to account for this?" I suspect you'd get an overparameterised model then.

Comment: Thank you for your help! @Glen_b, indeed, I found work from a group that developed a "partially overlapping samples t-test" (https://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol13-2/p120/p120.pdf), which seems a good way to go. As I also want to include covariates though, I still need to figure out a way for that.

Comment: @Christian Henning, using just random intercept may also be a good idea actually. Thanks!